# Not getting data in response for JAXBRepresentation in restlet

Tags: jaxb, osgi, restlet, apache-karaf

I am new to web services and currently trying to setup Restlet on Apache Karaf. My Core bundle starts component with Protocol: HTTP. And Port: 8081.

I have created a component in which uses HTTP Protocol and a port number configured via property.

Applications are attached to default host as

```
wsComponent.getDefaultHost().attach(restletApp.getURI(),restletApp);
```

In above getURI function returns URL to which application is attached.

I am trying to use JaxbRepresentation to get details. Server Resource class is as follows:

```
@Get
public Representation getAllUsers()
{
    List<MyUser> allUsers = MyFactory.getInstance().getAllUsers();
    MyUserListXML userListXML = new MyUserListXML(MyUserConverter.convertMyUserList(allUsers));
    JaxbRepresentation<MyUserListXML> userReps = new JaxbRepresentation<MyUserListXML>(userListXML);
    userReps.setFormattedOutput(true);
    return userReps;
}
```

MyUserListXML.java:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(propOrder={"user"})
@XmlRootElement(name="myUsers")
public class MyUserListXML implements Serializable
{

    private static final long   serialVersionUID    = 1L;
    @XmlElement(name="user")
    private List<MyUserXML> userList;

    public MyUserListXML()
    {
        // Default Constructor
    }

    /**
     * @param userList
     */
    public MyUserListXML(List<MyUserXML> userList)
    {
        this.userList = userList;
    }

    /**
     * @return the userList
     */
    public List<MyUserXML> getUserList()
    {
        return userList;
    }

    /**
     * @param userList the userList to set
     */
    public void setUserList(List<MyUserXML> userList)
    {
        this.userList = userList;
    }
}
```

MyUserXML.java

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(propOrder = {"id","userName","status","displayName","email"})
@XmlRootElement(name = "esmfUser")
public class MyUserXML implements Serializable
{

    private static final long   serialVersionUID    = 1L;

    @XmlElement(name= "id", required=true,type=Integer.class)
    private Integer userId;
    @XmlElement(required=true)
    private String  userName;
    @XmlElement(name="status",required=true)
    private String  userStatus;
    @XmlElement(required=true)
    private String  displayName;
    @XmlElement(required=true)
    private String  email;

    public MyUserXML()
    {
        // default constructor.
    }

    /**
     * @param userId
     * @param userName
     * @param userStatus
     * @param displayName
     * @param email
     */
    public MyUserXML(Integer userId, String userName, String userStatus, String displayName, String email)
    {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.userStatus = userStatus;
        this.displayName = displayName;
        this.email = email;
    }

    /**
     * @return the userId
     */
    public Integer getUserId()
    {
        return userId;
    }

    /**
     * @param userId the userId to set
     */
    public void setUserId(Integer userId)
    {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    /**
     * @return the userName
     */
    public String getUserName()
    {
        return userName;
    }

    /**
     * @param userName the userName to set
     */
    public void setUserName(String userName)
    {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    /**
     * @return the userStatus
     */
    public String getUserStatus()
    {
        return userStatus;
    }

    /**
     * @param userStatus the userStatus to set
     */
    public void setUserStatus(String userStatus)
    {
        this.userStatus = userStatus;
    }

    /**
     * @return the displayName
     */
    public String getDisplayName()
    {
        return displayName;
    }

    /**
     * @param displayName the displayName to set
     */
    public void setDisplayName(String displayName)
    {
        this.displayName = displayName;
    }

    /**
     * @return the email
     */
    public String getEmail()
    {
        return email;
    }

    /**
     * @param email the email to set
     */
    public void setEmail(String email)
    {
        this.email = email;
    }

}
```

While testing using soapUI I am getting following request and response

Request:

```
GET http://localhost:8081/ws/users HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Host: localhost:8081
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-encoding: gzip, zip, deflate
Server: Restlet-Framework/2.3.5
Date: Sun, 15 Nov 2015 09:29:31 GMT
Transfer-encoding: chunked
Content-type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8
Vary: Accept-Charset, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language, Accept
Accept-ranges: bytes
```

I am not sure why I am not getting xml data out. Can any one help me or guide me what I am doing wrong.

Restlet version: 2.3.5

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue.

I have created ObjectFactory class but changed its name. Due to this JaxbContext was not able to find ObjectFactory class. And since I am using restlet in Osgi and not yet able to figure out how to make Restlet use Osgi Log Service was not seeing any error messages from restlet.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the issue with JaxB, you should at least see a Warning log trace, and probably a IOException. I have a look at the issue you created (https://github.com/restlet/restlet-framework-java/issues/1166).
If you want to list all log traces from Restlet framework, and actually from any other kind of library that you include in your project and that don't rely on the OSGi LogService, you must configure the logs according to each library requirements (JUL, Log4j, slf4j, etc). As an OSGi container is basically a JVM, there is no issue to configure each logger.
Regarding Restlet Framework, you can read this page: http://restlet.com/technical-resources/restlet-framework/guide/2.3/editions/jse/logging
Some technologies such as slf4j helps to mutualize the different log systems. You should be able to pour all logs into the OSGi LogService, if you want to.